# Display date + day of week in datagrid using string format

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I want to display Sunday 31.01.2016 or 31.01.2016 Sunday 
I have to folowing binding in my datagrid:

```
Binding="{Binding Day, Mode=TwoWay,  StringFormat=\{0:d.dddd\}}"
```

So the closest to which I got is 31.Sunday but I want the whole date display + the Day of the week.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Sunday 31.01.2016:

```
Binding="{Binding Day, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat={}{0:dddd dd.MM.yyyy}}"
```

For 31.01.2016 Sunday

```
Binding="{Binding Day, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat={}{0:dd.MM.yyyy dddd}}"
```

You can read more about custom format strings [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx).

As to why I started the `StringFormat` with `{}`, you can read about that [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms744986(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks! Worked just as it should!